# Gridview Collapse expand android

Tags: android, animation, gridview, expand

I need a help. Expand or collapse of grid view.

Let me explain in words,

There are 6 rows in gidview. This will be shown on expand. Gridview will shrink to one row on collapse.

Hope this helps to understand my requirement.

Comment: you didn't attach a picture

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad, Sorry I could n't attach image. Please check requirement in words.

Comment: the number of gridview rows are fixed to 6 ? And they will not gonna change ?

Comment: yes, it is fixed to 6. Can't we change dynamically?

Comment: if every thing is fixed then you can do this in xml layout make custom six rows of gridviews like views & make 5 of them Visibility to gone & when expand then make all of them visible

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad : Thanks for your comment. I will try ur suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
expandButton.setonClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
   gridlist.addAll(templist); // adding all rows which are stored in temp list
   gridviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // will reflect and refreshes the ui to show 6 rows
  }

 });

collapseButton.setonClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
   gridlist.removeAll();// removing all rows
   gridlist.Add(templist.get(0));
   gridlist.Add(templist.get(1)); //adding only two items to list
   gridviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // will reflect and refreshes the ui to show 1st row 
 }

});
```